# Потоковое шифрование больших файлов в android

Tags: java, android, криптография

Есть необходимость шифровать zip-архив пользовательским паролем.
Я нашёл такое решение:
https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/storing-data-securely-on-android--cms-30558

Есть еще такой вариант:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613342/concatenating-mac-and-salt-with-ciphertext

Мне нужно с помощью вводимого пользователем пароля зашифровать zip-архив (как это показано в примере по ссылке), поместив в результирующий зашифрованный файл соль, вектор, и сам зашифрованный контент.
Получаю соль byte[256], вектор byte[16], с этим проблем нет.
Проблема в том - как записать в один файл соль, вектор и сам зашифрованный контент. В этих примерах, как и во многих других, сначала создается буфер со всем этим содержимым, а потом буфер записывается в файл.
Но что, если файл будет большой, например, 2 Гб? Получается при его шифровании весь его контент 2 Гб скопируется в буфер? А если в телефоне всего 2Гб оперативы, оператива исчерпается?

Поэтому я вижу выход в потоковом шифровании из FileInputStream в FileOutputStream с помощью CipherInputStresm или CipherOutputStream c использованием промежуточного буфера размером, наверное, 4096. Я даже и такие примеры находил

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361371/android-encryption-large-files

, но там была только запись самого шифра без добавления соли и вектора.

Главная проблема и вопрос: как при таком варианте поточного шифрования (без использования больших буферов в оперативной памяти) поместить в шифрованный файл (а при расшифровке извлечь) соль и вектор? Другими словами - каким способом записывать в один файл (а потом извлекать) соль, вектор и сам шифр?

Comment: Ну так сохраните сначала в файл соль и вектор, а потом дописывайте в него поток зашифрованных байтиков.

Comment: До этой идеи я догадался, но меня интересовали варианты реализации. Шифрование я сделал по образцу

https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/storing-data-securely-on-android--cms-30558, 

но там при расшифровке не проверяется ни пароль, ни целостность зашифрованного файла. Какие есть способы проверки введённого пароля до расшифровки файла, при условии что нет привязки ни к каким данным самого телефона, ни к ключам защищённого хранилища, ни к чему другому? Это чтобы можно было расшифровать файл паролем на другом устройстве. Как запароленный архив winrar.

Comment: И проверка целостности зашифрованного файла интересует, каким способом ее можно сделать в случае hmacSha1?